# Java iterator through excel rows

Tags: java, excel, apache

I am checking every excel row and looking for certain value. After I found that value it should print an output about that row location. But if that value is incorrect or not found I am printing match not found. So everytime I am doing this my output is always: Match not found.

P.S. barcode is my string value parsed from another class (I debugged it value is passed correctly).

Moreover if I write only if case without else if program can find that value, but in case of incorrect value I will get nothing.

My problem is that everytime I run that if cycle no mater if my barcode string is correct or not I always got match not found.

My task is to scan excel file and find a value which I need in this case barcode and print entire row, but if barcode is incorrect I need to print that match not found that user will able to know that barcode he entered is incorrect.

```
try {
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("Turto sarašas 2016.09.30.xlsx"));

        //Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

        //Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        //Iterate through each rows one by one
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            //For each row, iterate through all the columns
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                //Check the cell type and format accordingly
                final DataFormatter df = new DataFormatter();
                String valueAsString = df.formatCellValue(cell);
                if (valueAsString.equals(barcode)) {
                    System.out.print("Hello" + row.getCell(0));
                    System.out.print("Hello" + row.getCell(3));
                } else if (!valueAsString.equals(barcode)) {
                    System.out.println(" Match not found");
                }
            }
        }

        file.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
```

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-poi-reading-and-writing-excel-file-in-java/

Comment: 1. Never just skip exceptions because if there is one thrown you get the solution for a problem much faster. I'm not in the library you use but can the value be null? Maybe the value is null and you try to check if the value of a null string is the value you want. Maybe add a null check for the value before comparing the strings.

Comment: Value not null. Value is just a different string which is not listed in excel.

Comment: Don't know what the problem is, you should check what do you get from excel(what `valueAsString` equals to ) but your `else if` is pointless, it should be just `else`.

Comment: Add a simple `e.printStackTrace()` in the empty catch statement. And maybe put a counter instead of the 'Match not found' printout. And then print the counter's value after `file.close()`. Does the counter's value match the number of cells in your Excel file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code is working  as expected. If possible share that input xlsx to debug.

Comment: My input is 8k lines of: No match found. That is it no errors or smth like that. I even searched accross all the lines and couldn't see if my program found that 1 I was looking for.

Comment: Include below code to if statement and better comment out or delete else if statement. 
System.out.println( cell.getAddress().getRow() +" / "+ cell.getAddress().getColumn());

Comment: what getAddress stands for?

Comment: It's method which return row and column position currently you working on.

https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellAddress.html

Comment: But first of all you need to create Address object and after this you can call getColumn and getRow from that object, otherwise it wont gonna happen. Moreover if I delete else statement how I am going to tell user that match not found for barcode he enters?